# Prevent php file upload

Tags: php

How can i prevent user to upload php file in my input type file. I add this .htaccess in my upload folder, it's not working. Any idea ?

```
RemoveHandler .php .phtml .php3
RemoveType .php .phtml .php3
php_flag engine off
```

Comment: Check the file extension after they upload, if it's a PHP file, then reject it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what type of files users upload. You can only validate what they upload (then publish it, process it or discard it as you see fit).

Answer (score -2):

check the file type before uploading.

```
if($_FILES["uploadFile"]["type"] == "text/php"){
   //reject
 }
```

Comment: That checks the mimetype *after* uploading, and it's the mimetype assertedby the client - which should not be trusted.

Comment: Oops! Didn't  get the question. :(